# parse a string that contains array with strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I am struggling to parse a string that contains array. And the array also contains list of arrays.
Each of the array contains string.

code here

```js
let a = "[[48934, 'Danial Brendon', 'developer'],[48934, 'Nicki Lopez', 'developer']]";

console.log(JSON.parse(a))
```

I tried using `JSON.parse()` but did not work, may  be because `JSON.parse()` also want to parse the `string`.

I am having difficulty with this even this  looks simple. I could not find any similar question/answer like this.

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax of that is not valid JSON. You should fix whatever creates that input so that it gives you valid JSON instead - whatever's currently generating it can be considered essentially broken at the moment..

Comment: It's not impossible to parse what you have, but doing so would be a very X/Y solution.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.parse(a.replace(/'/g, '"')))`

Answer (score 1):

To JSON parse , you need double quotes instead of single. like this ...

```js
let a = '[[48934, "Danial Brendon", "developer"],[48934, "Nicki Lopez", "developer"]]';
console.log(JSON.parse(a));
```